# Method to mass update User Service Cloud?

Tags: userlicense

We are doing a transition from Service Cloud to Platform License for hundreds of users, and the approach of manually updating one user at a time via UI would be painfully slow.

When we've explored methods for bulk transfer we've run into walls. Apex and data loader are apparently not permitted to update the user license (at least our tests so far reveal). Salesforce themselves say they are not able to mass migrate users on our behalf.

Is there a way we're not thinking of?

Update: The issue is apparently not with the straight license transition, but rather specifically for those with 'Service Cloud User' checked on their user record. I'm looking for a way to disable this first programmatically to be able to migrate the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API name for the 'Service Cloud User' checkbox shown on the user page layout is "USERPERMISSIONSSUPPORTUSER" so if that is causing an issue during the update, you can set to to false before changing the user's license type.

Query for reference,

```
Select USERPERMISSIONSSUPPORTUSER from user
```

Comment: yup that's it thank you